# SQL : get all users in many specific group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL problem which seem simple but I can't find the solution...

I have 3 tables :

1) "user" (id, lastname, firstname)

2) "user_x_group" (id_user, id_group)

3) "group" (id, name)

A "user" can have many "group".

What is the query to get all the users in the group 1 and the group 2 at the same time ?

```
SELECT *
FROM user u 
JOIN user_x_group x ON x.id_user = u.id 
WHERE id_group IN ('1', '2')
```

is not correct because I get all users in group 1 + all users in group 2 + all users in group 1&2. I just need all users in group 1&2 in one query.

How to do that ?

Comment: So if user A is in both group 1 and group 2, will they have two records in the user_x_group table?

Comment: @evanv : yes, they have two records in the user_x_group table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY` and require (`HAVING`) more than one different id_group's are found

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u 
JOIN user_x_group x ON x.id_user = u.id 
WHERE id_group IN ('1', '2') 
group by u.id
having count(distinct id_group) >= 2
```

You can easily adjust to 3 or more id_groups if needed.

Alternative `HAVING` clause, for exactly 2 groups:

```
having max(id_group) <> min(id_group)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM user u 
JOIN user_x_group x ON x.id_user = u.id and x.id_group = 1
JOIN user_x_group x1 ON x.id_user = x1.id_user and x1.id_group = 2
```

You can `join` twice once for each `id_group` condition to get all users in both the groups.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method using `EXISTS` in case you have more than two groups and you only want those two:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    Select *
    From user_x_group x
    Where x.id_user = u.id 
    And x.id_group = '1'
)
AND EXISTS 
(
    Select *
    From user_x_group x2
    Where x2.id_user = u.id 
    And x2.id_group = '2'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM user 
WHERE
id in (select distinct id_user as id from user_x_group where id_group='1')
AND 
id in (select distinct id_user as id from user_x_group where id_group='2')
```